# Ways to increment hex in python?

Tags: python

I cannot come up with a way to increment a hex value. Let's say I have a variable 
x = b'\x00' and I just want to keep incrementing it forever in that format how would I do it? x=b'\x00' ...x='\xff'...x='\xff\xff' . Again I want to keep it as a string variable, doesn't have to be hex format but I just want to start at 0 bits and increment to whatever bits.

Comment: Why are you not starting with a number in the first place?

Comment: "Keep it as a string" *why*? Is there **any** compelling reason not to convert to a number, and then back to a string on output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3, the easiest way is to use a number which you convert with to `bytes` with the `to_bytes` method of `int`:

```
for i in range(0xffff + 1):
    # The "or 1" ensures 0 produces b'\x00' as output, not b''
    x = i.to_bytes((i.bit_length() + 7) // 8 or 1, 'big')
```

That loop produces all the values you specified (from `b'\x00'` to `b'\xff\xff'`), and can be trivially tweaked for any arbitrary range you care about.

There are other ways to generate new `bytes` objects directly (easier with `bytearray`, but `bytes` can be done), but they're needlessly complex, and likely slower to boot, e.g. incrementing a `bytearray`, but I'd avoid it in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  What exactly is  going on from I.bit_length part ?

Comment: @bbymintdrop: You need to convert the bit length to the byte length, rounding up (because 1-8 bits requires 1 byte, 9-16 requires 2, etc.). `//` is floor division, but ceil division can be defined as `(num + (den - 1)) // den`; since it's pure integer math, it's faster and guaranteed accurate in a way that `math.ceil(num / den)` would not be.